# SvelteKit Pass Data From Server to Browser

Tags: cookies, server-side-rendering, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to pass data from the server to the client to load my app faster and prevent multiple calls to the database.

#### Via Fetch

SvelteKit is made to do this via the [fetch](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/loading#input-fetch) function. This is great if you have an endpoint that allows for custom fetch. But what if you don't?

**Firebase** is a perfect example of not having a custom `fetch` function.

#### Cookies

I would think I could use cookies, but when I set the cookie, it just prints 'undefined' and never gets set.

```js
<script lang="ts" context="module">
    import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
    import { browser } from '$app/env';
    import { getResources } from '../modules/resource';

    export async function load() {

        if (browser) {

            // working code would use JSON.parse
            const c = Cookies.get('r');
            return {
                props: {
                    resources: c
                }
            };
        } else {

            // server
            const r = await getResources();

            // working code would use JSON.stringify
            Cookies.set('resources', r);

            // no cookies were set?
            console.log(Cookies.get());
            return {
                props: {
                    resources: r
                }
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

So my code loads correctly, then dissapears when the browser `load` function is loaded...

Surely there is a functioning way to do this?

J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems the [official](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/3729) answer by Rich Harris is to use and a rest api endpoint AND fetch.

**routes/something.ts**

```js
import { getFirebaseDoc } from "../modules/posts";

export async function get() {
    return {
        body: await getFirebaseDoc()
    };
}
```

**routes/content.svelte**

```js
export async function load({ fetch }) {
  const res = await fetch('/resources');
  if (res.ok) {
    return {
      props: { resources: await res.json() }
    };
  }
  return {
    status: res.status,
    error: new Error()
  };
}
```

This seems extraneous and problematic as I speak of [here](https://dev.to/jdgamble555/passing-state-from-the-server-to-the-browser-in-sveltekit-37co), but it also seems like the only way.

J

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a handler that injects the cookie into the server response (because load functions do not expose the request or headers to the browser, they are just used for loading props I believe). Example here: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/59358960ff2c32d714c47957a2350f459b9ccba8/packages/kit/test/apps/basics/src/hooks.js#L42

https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#handle

```js
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
    event.locals.user = await getUserInformation(event.request.headers.get('cookie'));

    const response = await resolve(event);
    response.headers.set('x-custom-header', 'potato');
    response.headers.append('set-cookie', 'name=SvelteKit; path=/; HttpOnly');


    return response;
}
```

FYI: This functionality was only added 11 days ago in `@sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.267`: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/3631

Comment: Appreciate it!  However, this does not solve my use case.

Answer (score 1):

#### No need to use fetch!

You can get the data however you like!

```html
<script context="module">
    import db from '$/firebaseConfig'

    export async function load() {
        const eventref = db.ref('cats/whiskers');
        const snapshot = await eventref.once('value');
        const res = snapshot.val();

        return { props: { myData: res.data } } // return data under `props` key will be passed to component
    }
</script>

<script>
    export let myData //data gets injected into your component
</script>


<pre>{JSON.stringify(myData, null, 4)}</pre>
```

Here's a quick demo on how to fetch data using axios, same principle applies for firebase: https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-bpr1uq?file=src/routes/index.svelte

---

If you want to **only load data on the server** you should use an "endpoint" (https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#endpoints)

Comment: Thanks for responding, but this is how it works by loading 2 times.  I want to pass the data with cookies so I don't read the database twice.

Answer (score 0):

My solution might solve it especially for those who work with (e.g: laravel_session), actually in your case if you want to retain the cookie data when loading on each endpoint.

What you should gonna do is to create an interface to pass the event on every api() call

```
interface ApiParams {
    method: string;
    event: RequestEvent<Record<string, string>>;
    resource?: string;
    data?: Record<string, unknown>;
}
```

Now we need to modify the default sveltekit api(), provide the whole event.

```
// localhost:3000/users
export const get: RequestHandler = async (event) => {
    const response = await api({method: 'get', resource: 'users', event});
    // ...
});
```

Inside your `api()` function, set your `event.locals` but make sure to update your `app.d.ts`

```
// app.d.ts
declare namespace App {
    interface Locals {
        r: string;
    }
    //...
}

// api.ts
export async function api(params: ApiParams) {
    // ...
    params.event.locals.r = response.headers.get('r')
});
```

Lastly, update your `hooks.ts`

```
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Handle} */
export const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    const cookies = cookie.parse(event.request.headers.get('cookie') || '');
    const response = await resolve(event);

    if (!cookies.whatevercookie && event.locals.r) {
        response.headers.set(
            'set-cookie',
            cookie.serialize('whatevercookie', event.locals.r, {
                path: '/',
                httpOnly: true
            })
        );
    }
    
    return response;
});
```

**Refer to my project:**

- [hooks.ts](https://github.com/daison12006013/gorvel/blob/develop/resources/sveltekit-starter/src/hooks.ts)
- [app.d.ts](https://github.com/daison12006013/gorvel/blob/develop/resources/sveltekit-starter/src/app.d.ts)
- [_api.ts](https://github.com/daison12006013/gorvel/blob/develop/resources/sveltekit-starter/src/routes/_api.ts)
- [index.ts](https://github.com/daison12006013/gorvel/blob/develop/resources/sveltekit-starter/src/routes/guest/index.ts)